# FBConnect facebook.stream.publish with NSDictionary problems

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, fbconnect

I have this code that can't send a Facebook request until now.

```
NSDictionary *firstDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"image", @"Type",
    @"http://mysite.com/image.jpg", @"src",
    @"http://mysite.com/page.html", @"href",
    nil];
NSDictionary *secondDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"image", @"Type",
    @"http://mysite.com/image.jpg", @"src",
    @"http://mysite.com/page.html", @"href",
    nil];
NSArray *mediaArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:firstDict, secondDict, nil];

NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"name", @"description", @"href", @"media", nil];
NSArray *objects = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [NSString stringWithString:@"MyTitle"],
    [NSString stringWithString:@"My caption"],
    [NSString stringWithString:@"http://mysite.com/page.html"], mediaArray, nil];

NSDictionary *attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:objects forKeys:keys];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.stream.publish" params:attachment];
```

I took this sample : http://forum.developers.facebook.com/viewtopic.php?pid=145965

But every time I run it, the console shows the following:

```
 {
     "api_key" = adc8d70987098sdc;
     "call_id" = 23456767;
     description = "Any user's description";
     format = XML;
     href = "http://mysite.com/page.html";
     media =     (
                 {
             Type = image;
             href = "http://mysite.com/page.html";
             src = "http://mysite.com/image.jpg";
         },
                 {
             Type = image;
             href = "http://mysite.com/page.html";
             src = "http://mysite.com/image.jpg";
         }
     );
     method = "Facebook.streamPublish";
     name = aName;
     "session_key" = "d0f98bfs89b7fg7v";
     sig = 89v0d9fv879fgv;
     ss = 1;
     v = "1.0"; }
```

It shows parentheses for array instead brackets, is that normal?.

Then it displays the error:

```
*** -[NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
     0x12fcb0 2009-10-30 13:54:27.758 GeoPixr[307:207]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
*** -[NSCFArray dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x12fcb0
```

The [session resume] call returns TRUE.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to send the dictionary with an array but there's another class that works for me:

```
FBStreamDialog
```

Which brings up a dialog before it sends the information and it's delegate methods lets you know about changes.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using latest [iOS SDK For Facebook](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/how-to-develop-facebook-application-for-iphone/) then using the below method you can publish image as a stream.

```
- (IBAction) publishStream: (id)sender {

  SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://thinkdiff.net",@"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];
  NSDictionary* imageShare = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"image", @"type",
                                @"http://thinkdiff.net/mahmud_small.jpg", @"src",
                                @"http://thinkdiff.net", @"href",
                                nil];

  NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"a long run", @"name",
                               @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                               @"it is fun", @"description",
                               @"http://itsti.me/", @"href",
                               [NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageShare, nil ], @"media",
                              nil];
  NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];
    NSLog(attachmentStr);
  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 kAppId, @"api_key",
                                 @"Share on Facebook",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                 attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                 nil];

  [_facebook dialog: @"stream.publish"
          andParams: params
        andDelegate:self];
}
```

The image part should be another NSDictionary object.

```
NSDictionary* imageShare = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                @"image", @"type",
                                @"http://thinkdiff.net/mahmud_small.jpg", @"src",
                                @"http://thinkdiff.net", @"href",
                                nil];
```

And in the attachment NSDictionary object must include imageShare object as array

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:imageShare, nil ]
```

This is because if you not include this as an array, Json parser avoid [] brackets as a result the publish functionality will not work. Remember the string needs to be a valid JSON string otherwise facebook api will not publish.

Comment: this help me a lot, thanks! I can't believe Facebook does't give any examples.

Answer (score 0):

`dataUsingEncoding:` is a `NSString` method, so presumably, some object is expecting an instance of `NSString` where you passed an array. I presume that FBRequest cannot deal with the array you included in the `attachment` dictionary.

Comment: Yeah, I've even tested the same code, first, writing the complete string an then applying the [string JSONValue] (just in case...) but the result is the same  . WhatI don't understand is why these guys don't have preoblems with the request using a dictionary. uhmmmm....

Answer (score 0):

I modified your example a little and it works. Here's the working code:

```
NSString *att = @"{\"name\":\"i\'m bursting with joy\",\"caption\": \"User rated the lolcat 5 stars\", \"description\": \"a funny looking cat\"}";
NSDictionary *attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:att forKey:@"attachment"];
[[FBRequest requestWithDelegate:self] call:@"facebook.stream.publish" params:attachment];
```